# gunicorn can't find the django wsgi module

Tags: django, gunicorn

I am trying to set up gunicorn for Django by following this [blog](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). I created the `gunicorn_start` script and gave it permission:

```
$ sudo chown -R hello:users /webapps/hello_django
$ sudo chmod -R g+w /webapps/hello_django
```

Made it executable:

```
$ sudo chmod u+x bin/gunicorn_start
```

But when I run this comman:

```
advenio@advenio-VirtualBox:~$ sudo su - hello
$ bin/gunicorn_start
```

It gives me an error:

```
advenio@advenio-VirtualBox:~$ sudo su - hello
$ bin/gunicorn_start
Starting hello_app as hello
bin/gunicorn_start: line 26: /webapps/hello_django/hello/../bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
```

This the `gunicorn_start` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="hello_app"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/hello_django/hello             # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/hello_django/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=hello                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=hello.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=hello.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had to remove

```
../bin
```

from

```
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
```

Now, its just:

```
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
```

Hope this will help someone as me.